# Convert script src's into quick '//= require' statements in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

My designer has given me tons of script src's in the static HTML page something like :

```
<script src="../vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/nprogress/nprogress.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/Chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/jquery-sparkline/dist/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
<script src="js/flot/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
<script src="js/flot/date.js"></script>
<script src="js/flot/jquery.flot.spline.js"></script>
<script src="js/flot/curvedLines.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/datepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>

<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

The list goes on etc.

So to put them up in rails, I need to individually copy them and put it up in my application.js file like so ( just an example ) :

```
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require fastclick
//= require nprogress
//= require Chart.min
... etc ...
```

I was wondering, if anyone has figured out an easier method than copy pasting the name individually? I make a ton of mistakes while copy pasting and when the number of assets are huge, it gets really irritating.

My IDE supports RegEx, what would be an appropriate regex to select only the required asset name from script or link=stylesheet source?

For example:

```
<script src="js/datepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
```

Select **daterangepicker** from this. ( Please note that it does not have the .js extension )

And similarly :

```
<link href="/assets/admin/custom.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Select **custom** from the above link statement? ( It does not have the .css extension. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
(?<=\/)[^\/]+(?=(?:\.(?:js|css)"))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uX5mQ8/1)

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thank you! :)